# Blog like post?

Tags: support

So I would like to talk about something that could really help parents (many answers talk about this already) understand their kids and their behaviour. As it would be formed blog like instead of Q-A like, I'm not sure if there's any possible way of doing that (most similar thing I know from here is a openning a wiki or to answer your own question).

Comment: What are you thinking about discussing?  If we had a better idea of what you want to do, we can either help you make sure it fits within the rules of the site or be able to direct you to a more appropriate place.  That being said, remember that questions should be about [actual problems you face](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/actual-problems-that-you-face) and should be an actual question.  Also, why not just create your own blog and write the post there?

Comment: I'll start from the last statement, I don't want to create a personal blog as this is bigger and will get and help more people. Yes, it's an actual problem I can't face as I'm not a father but I see members of my family facing. Problem is: no, it's not a question (could be made anytime by someone) but it's the answer (or a part of it) to many questions. I'd basically talk about how to interact with kids, how to talk with them and how to understand the problems they(and their parents) are facing.

Comment: So, just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, the subject matter of this post would be about how parents and children can communicate to better understand the problems they are facing?  (I also assume this would be framed in fairly broad terms instead of how to talk about a certain, specific problem and would be more like general strategies.)

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange is explicitly not blog-like, and not discussion-focused, and while some SE sites do have their own blog, this is by no means the norm, and in fact the process for creating new SE blogs has been discontinued.

The huge advantage SE has over discussion-based forums is the way writers have to move away from discussion and opinion in order to deliver answers. This is called out by many folks as one of the reasons they like Parenting.SE - a lot of the potential for conflict and argument is removed.

If however you create a blog, you could link to it from your profile, or in chat, and even as supporting evidence in a post. It could not be a link-only answer, though, as those get closed very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is always the possibility of asking a good question and then answering it yourself, providing some kind of reference answer. However, you should allow for the possibility of other answers. That's how Stack Exchange works, different answers compete.